# AlethOne : GPU can't allocate the DAG in a single chunk

Tags: mining, mining-pools, gpu, alethone

I'm trying to do some pool mining using AlethOne, but get the following error:

```
Allocating/mapping single buffer failed with: "clEnqueueWriteBuffer(-4). GPU can't allocate the DAG in a single chunk. Bailing."
```

I'm currently using [these instructions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1156674.0), so I've entered

```
http://ethereumpool.co/?miner=20@0xe425AFC9cC425E88f911Ba9d4E77Eef763bCef22
```

in the Pool URL field.

Best guess would be that it's equivalent to the `-G` that I always have to remove in the consolue version of ethminer. Could anyone help ?

Comment: Seems there isn't enough GPU RAM to write the DAG.

Comment: Which GPU do you use?

Comment: @Cibils Thomas, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 4):

You have to set some environment variables.

Linux:

```
export GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE=100
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
```

Windows:

```
setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
```

Comment: input all variables and still does not work